# GitHUB error:1407742E:SSL Even after Updating to latest version

Tags: windows, git, github

I am getting this error when I try to push to github "error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version"

YES I have seen all the questions with answers that say to update my github version on windows. I did update my version and have the latest versions of both github installed and tortiseGit. If I try to push through the CMD prompt I get that error.

If I push through tortise I get a error (warning: unsupported ssl version tslv1.2: using default) but it does push. I would like to be able to push through my CMD Prompt however. and I've tried just about everything so far that I've found online but nothing fixes the issue.

Update:
If I go to cmd and type git --version I get "version 1.9.5.chromium.6" however if i goto git bash and request the version i get "version 2.17.0.windows.1

Comment: What version of Windows are you running?  What is the output of `git --version` on the cmd prompt?

Comment: you might have multiple versions of git installed, check your environment variables

Comment: If I go to cmd and type git --version I get "version 1.9.5.chromium.6" however if i goto git bash and request the version i get "version 2.17.0.windows.1"